# Is there a limit to how many times a particular scanner can be used?

Tags: no-mans-sky

There are a number of scanners around each world in No Man's Sky that help identify interesting locations on that world.

You get 4 options - and I've been going around crafting bypass keys and selecting each one once at each scanner.

But I got to wondering a couple of things:

1. Does the scanner find the same monolith each time?
2. Is there a limit to how many times I can use the scanner? Or is it simply limited to the number of bypass keys I can craft when I'm next to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the surface scanners an unlimited number of times, limited only by how many bypass keys you can make. After a while, however, it will start to notify you of locations it has already found. I know this because I'm searching for Atlas Pass plans, and only scanning for Colonial Outposts. After about 6 or 7 scans in a smaller area, it began to show me the same locations I had already visited.

Comment: Did it show you places you found before you got to the scanner, or did it actually mark the same place twice with two different scans?

Comment: @Kat It eventually marked the same spot with two different scans.